# Error NoReverseMatch on URL

Tags: django

Can someone explain what this error means and how to solve?

This is the error message:

****NoReverseMatch at /contacts/group/new/
Reverse for ''group_list'' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.****

**the urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',


             url(r'^$', 'contacts.views.home', name="group_list"),

             (r'^group/new/$', 'contacts.views.group', {}, 'group_new'),
             (r'^group/edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'contacts.views.group', {}, 'group_edit'),



)
```

**the template.py**

```
  <li>
   <a href="{% url 'group_list' %}">
      <i class="icon-group"></i>
       <span>Contacts</span>
</a>
</li>
```

Comment: get rid of the `'` in your template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clean your patterns up a bit by leveraging the `prefix` argument:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('contacts.views',
    url(r'^group/edit/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'group', name='group_edit'),
    url(r'^group/new/$', 'group', name='group_new'),
    url(r'^$', 'home', name="group_list"),
)
```

and when you use the url template tag, just provide the name of the pattern, instead of handing in a string literal to the function:

```
{% url group_list %}
```

Since patterns are matched in order, I would recommend putting the most specific patterns first, otherwise you might get some unexpected behavior.

Comment: If I did not do it as a string I use to get error on 1.5, but when I try it again I didn't, I'm confused. When should I use the name of the pattern vs the a string.

Comment: Well, it seems the URL syntax has changed slightly in 1.5 (I have yet to upgrade, as most of my projects leverage Django-CMS). It appears as though you *should* pass in the name of the pattern as a string in 1.5

Comment: but I'm running 1.5 and your code does not error (I'm sure it use to like that)

Comment: Interesting. They may not have removed all of the backwards compatibility in how the url template tag works.